# Properly upper casing a lower case string

Tags: python, user-input, uppercase, casing

I am writing a morse code that converts text to morse and morse to text. I have gotten pretty far. The problem I have left is how to print it and maybe a smarter way to deal with the errors.

I want the output of the code to be according to real writing rules. So if the input is 'hello, how are you? good thanks!' in morse, then I want the output to be 'Hello, how are you? Good thanks!',in text.

first I thought that I just had to manipulate the return value in the from_morse and to_morse functions.like this:

```
value[0]+value[1:].lower()
```

but that just covers the headcharacter to be big and not if a new sentence begins.

But is creating a function that controlls the return value a better approach or should I include the controll in my functions? in that case, how should I do it?

Here is the code:

```
tomorse = { } (is a dict with text-Values and morse-Keys. in upper() stile)

frommorse = dict((b,a) for a,b in tomorse.items())



def from_morse(text):
    value = ''
    for word in text.split(' '):
        if word == '':
            value += ' '
        #split the line into words
        for char in word.split():
            #split the word into characters
            if char in frommorse:
                value += frommorse[char].upper()
            else:
                print('Value for' ,char,' not found as morse.')
    return value



def to_morse(text):
    value = ''
    for char in text:
        if char in tomorse:
            value += tomorse[char] + ' '
        elif char == ' ':
            value += ' '
        else:
            print('Value for' ,char, 'not found as character.')
            break
    return value




def text_controll():
    while True:
        try:
            text = input('Enter what you want to convert: ').upper()
            if text.startswith(('.','-')):
                print('Your translation to text is:',from_morse(text))
            else:
                print('Your translation to morse is: ',to_morse(text))
        except (EOFError,KeyboardInterrupt):
            print('Thanks and Godbye!')
            break


text_controll()
```

Comment: hi! so from a string of text you want to detect sentence boundaries and capitalize accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

For your own sanity `from_morse` and `to_morse` should do what they say: convert to text and to morse as required.

You can then write another function to convert a sentence into a sentence with capitals and punctuation.

You could detect the end of a sentence by looking for dots, exclamation marks and question marks. However someone could also write "how are you ???" which means you don't want to detect the sentences "How are you ?", "?" and "?". In other words: you also need to detect sequences of character that could end a sentence.

Another issue is that someone might use a punctuation character in the sentence such as mentioning the company name Yahoo!.

Comment: Detecting a punctuation mark followed by a space `"! "` would work in most cases "Hello!!! How are you??" But again you have the issue of punctuated names, quotation marks, etc.